# Type mismatch for number in Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have an array and the second column with values like this `2050.878456` and inside my javascript function to create a Area Chart I made the following

```
function drawVisualization() {
    var data = null;
    data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
    data.addRows(myArrayCreated);
    // Create and draw the visualization.
    var ac = new google.visualization.AreaChart(document
            .getElementById('visualization_chart'));
    ac.draw(data, {
        title : 'Results',
        isStacked : true,
        width : 700,
        height : 400,
        vAxis : {title : "kW"},
        hAxis : {title : "Day"}
    });

}
```

however I get this error `Type mismatch. Value 2050.878456 does not match type number in column index 1` however it cannot be a string type as well, why do I get this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting `Value` as a `number`?  Did you check if it is a `string` by any chance?  This is one of the most common errors.

Comment: I changed for string as you said like this `data.addColumn('string', 'Value');
        for (i = 0; i < myArrayCreated.length; i++){
         data.addRow(myArrayCreated[i][0] , parseFloat(myArrayCreated[i][1]).toFixed(6));
        }` however get this error `If argument is given to addRow, it must be an array, or null`

Comment: Do this instead: `for (var i=0;i<myArrayCreated.length;i++){
    myVal = parseFloat($.trim(myArrayCreated[i][0]));
    data.addRow([i, {v: myVal, f: myval.toFixed(6)}]);
}`

Comment: it should be `myVal = parseFloat($.trim(myArrayCreated[i][1]));`...   my bad..

Comment: thank you very much!! it really helped me! since I'm new with javascript I don't know where should I put my myArrayCreated[i][0] should it be `data.addRow([ myArrayCreated[i][0], {
    v : myVal,
    f : myVal.toFixed(6)
   } ]);` if yes I get the same error.. thank you!

Comment: Oh sorry it was my error... I forgot to change it to number again! Thank you very much again!

Comment: No problem.. Happy learning.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try passing the `Value` as `string` and then later do a `parseFloat`.  Something like this:

```
data.addColumn('string', 'Value');

for (var i=0;i<myArrayCreated.length;i++){
    myVal = parseFloat($.trim(myArrayCreated[i][1])); 
    data.addRow([i, {v: myVal, f: myval.toFixed(6)}]); 
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I spotted the same issue.

not working:

```
data.addRow([v, obd[v].engine_rpm]);
```

working:

```
data.addRow([v, Number(obd[v].engine_rpm)]);
```

[image: wtf]

Comment: Thank you friend !! the Number() saved me :)

Comment: Nice dude. it is work for me