# google timeLine chart

Tags: javascript, datetime, charts, google-visualization, timeline

im trying to create a timeline chart but im facing a problem with date format i get this **error**

> (Value Invalid Date does not match type date in column index 2)

and this is my **code** :

```
google.charts.load("current", { packages: ["timeline"] });
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(initTimeLineChart);

function initTimeLineChart(obj) {
    console.log(obj)
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline1');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'DriverName' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Activity' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    var datas = '';
    $.each(obj,
        function (i, v) {

            if (i === 0) {
                datas = '["' + v.DriverName + '", "' + v.Activity + '","' + convert(v.Start) + '","' + convert(v.End) + '"]';
            } else {
                datas = datas + ',["' + v.DriverName + '", "' + v.Activity + '","' + convert(v.Start) + '","' + convert(v.End) + '"]';
            }

        });
    datas = '[' + datas + ']';
    console.log(datas);
    dataTable.addRows(JSON.parse(datas));
    var options = {
        timeline: { singleColor: '#8d8' }
    };

    chart.draw(dataTable, options);
}
function convert(str) {
    var month, day, year, hours, minutes, seconds;
    var date = new Date(str),
        month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    hours = ("0" + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
    minutes = ("0" + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
    year = ("20 "+date.getYear());
    console.log(date);
    return new Date(year, 0, day, hours, minutes, 0);
}
```

Comment: At which line you are getting error?

Comment: dataTable.addRows(JSON.parse(datas));

Comment: what is drawChart? What do you get in console after executing line `console.log(datas);` Please provide complete code

Comment: i get somthing like this :

Comment: [
 ["FERRER Patrick", "BreakRest", "2018-04-24 00:00:00", "2018-04-24 05:59:00"],
 ["FERRER Patrick", "Drive", "2018-04-24 05:59:00", "2018-04-24 06:33:00"],
 ["FERRER Patrick", "Work", "2018-04-24 06:33:00", "2018-04-24 06:38:00"],
 ["FERRER Patrick", "Drive", "2018-04-24 06:38:00", "2018-04-24 06:39:00"],
 ["FERRER Patrick", "Work", "2018-04-24 06:39:00", "2018-04-24 06:53:00"],
 ["FERRER Patrick", "Drive", "2018-04-24 06:53:00", "2018-04-24 07:29:00"],
 ["FERRER Patrick", "Work", "2018-04-24 07:29:00", "2018-04-24 07:32:00"],

Comment: drawChat  was a mistake it's the name of th function initTimeLineChart

Comment: Did you checked this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24365731/type-mismatch-for-number-in-google-chart-api/24367948

Comment: yes i did , but im facing a another problem i think.

Comment: Nice! Glad you found the fix. If you can share what was the fix it might help future reader.

Comment: function ToJavaScriptDate(value) {
        var array = value.split('-');
        console.log(array);
        var year, month, day, hour, minutes;
        year = array[0];
        day = array[2].split('T')[0];
        month = array[1];
        hour = array[2].split('T')[1].split(':')[0];
        minutes = array[2].split('T')[1].split(':')[1];
        var date = new Date(parseFloat(year), parseFloat(month), parseFloat(day), parseFloat(hour), parseFloat(minutes), 0);
        console.log(date);
        return date;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of building an array from a string,
just use an actual array, along with the `addRow` mtheod

replace all this...

```
var datas = '';
$.each(obj,
    function (i, v) {

        if (i === 0) {
            datas = '["' + v.DriverName + '", "' + v.Activity + '","' + convert(v.Start) + '","' + convert(v.End) + '"]';
        } else {
            datas = datas + ',["' + v.DriverName + '", "' + v.Activity + '","' + convert(v.Start) + '","' + convert(v.End) + '"]';
        }

    });
datas = '[' + datas + ']';
console.log(datas);
dataTable.addRows(JSON.parse(datas));
```

with...

```
$.each(obj, function (i, v) {
  dataTable.addRow([
    v.DriverName,
    v.Activity,
    convert(v.Start),
    convert(v.End)
  ]);
});
```